# SQL Server: select rows which has particular id in their json column

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I have a table with two columns: [ID] and [Content] (with ISJSON constraint, so every row must have valid JSON in [Content] column).
These JSONs have an array field, which consists of objects with some specific ID (and many more fields) .

```
    {
    "departments": [ { "id": 1, "fieldA": "somevalue" }, 
                     { "id": 2, "fieldA": "somevalue" }]
    }
```

**I'd like to perform a select query, which returns all rows with some particular id in the object from departments field.**

I managed to create a script that uses a cursor fetching departments field from [Content] column into @content variable and then:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@content) WITH(id int) WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 9)
```

But it returns only departmentid and I need the whole row.
Preferably it should look like that (but code below unfortunately does not work):

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM I WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(I.CONTENT) WITH(id int) WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this could get you what you need:

```
declare @someId varchar(10) = '1'
declare @json nvarchar(1000) = N'{ "departments": [ { "id": 1, "fieldA": "somevalue" },  { "id": 1, "fieldA": "test" },  { "id": 2, "fieldA": "somevalue" }] }'

select ids.[key], ids.[value] id_val, depts.value content
from openjson(@json, '$.departments') as depts cross apply OPENJSON(depts.value) as ids
where ids.[key] = 'id' and ids.value = @someId
```

I have added another element to the `departments` array, with the same `Id = 1` just for testing the results.

> EDIT:

```
select  ids.[key], ids.[value] id_val, depts.value content
from ITEMS i cross apply openjson(i.Content, '$.departments') as depts cross apply OPENJSON(depts.value) as ids
where ids.[key] = 'id' and ids.value = @id
```

Comment: That looks promising, thanks! Now I have table which contains many rows with json data. How could I use your snippet to solve this problem? I'm used to vectorized functions from languages like R and I was disappointed when I saw that:

`declare @id nvarchar(2) = '17'


select ids.[key], ids.[value] id_val, depts.value content
from openjson((SELECT CONTENT FROM ITEM),  '$.departments') as depts cross apply OPENJSON(depts.value) as ids
where ids.[key] = 'departmentid' and ids.value = @id`

returns `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error :(

Comment: Hm, yes, because your select is getting all `Content` values from your `ITEM` table. You need to apply this one by one, for each `Content` column.
I am thinking of either cross apply with your source table _OR_ building a dynamic query..I will give the first scenario a try.

Comment: If I could make an assumption that only one row in my table has json with that id in json, I would use SELECT TOP 1. Unfortunately this assumption is wrong.

Comment: Happy to help! :)